# Fetchrequest with NSPredicate not returning right values

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm having a strange problem with Core Data.
The problem is that I'm looking for objects with a property less than X and it isn't returning all the values that matches.
There is no cache and I'm not using     //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50];

```
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.level <= [cd] %@", [self.filters objectForKey:@"level"]];
```

I add it to a MutableArray of predicates and later I execute
        NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates];

This one it's in a function that returns myPredicate called preparePredicates. For the moment there aren't more predicates, only one.
It's NSLog returns: level <=[cd] "30".
I have tried it also with intValue of the string and %i
The main function:

```
NSError* error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myEntity"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate* predicate = [self preparePredicates]; 
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

//[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog (@"Error: %@", error);
NSLog(@"los fetchedobjects: %i",[fetchedObjects count]);
return fetchedObjects;
```

It doesn't return any error.
If I look at the results there isn't one having a level of 6, but there are others that matches (all are less than the specified). I know there is one with level 6. 
If I open the .sqlite in SQLite Database Browser, I can see it there. 
If I do with this program a

```
SELECT * FROM zmyentity WHERE zlevel <30;
```

it doesn't appear, same as in Core Data do. But if I do a 
    SELECT * FROM zmyentity WHERE zlevel == 6;
it appears.
I really don't know what is happening. Maybe I'm making a rookie mistake, so please point me in the right direction.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have stored the level as a *String* attribute, because

```
"30" < "6"
```

when comparing strings. Choosing a numeric attribute type (Integer 16/32/64) should solve the problem. The corresponding `level` property in the `myEntity` class has then the `NSNumber` type.

You should also omit the `[cd]` modifier in the predicate, because that enforces a string comparison.

You predicate could then look like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.level <= %d", [[self.filters objectForKey:@"level"] intValue]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it was the source of the problem.
Also, as using an NSNumber, predicateWithFormat has to be with object reference %@ to work properly, not double.

        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.level <= %@", [self.filters objectForKey:@"level"]];

Comment: @CarlosPastor: You can do it both ways: `%@` with an `NSNumber` object, or `%d` with an integer argument, both does work. - I suggested `%d` with `[[self.filters objectForKey:@"level"] intValue]` argument because I did not know whether the "level" is a number or a string.